# Changes fragments with sequential animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I can't found how make animation between two fragments sequential. Is it possible?
For example. I have fragmentA and fragmentB. I can make animation

```
 getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_fade_in, R.anim.fragment_fade_out)
                    .replace(fragmentB)
                    .commit();
```

But animations shows together. I need scenario:

1. remove fragmentA with animation
2. waiting some ms
3. add fragmentB with animation

I found solution, but I think it's not good.

```
Handler mSequentiallyFrgAnimHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
   //first remove preview fragment
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(0, R.anim.fragment_fade_out)
                    .remove(fragmentA)
                    .commit();
 //we need animations sequentially, wait 400ms between animations
 mSequentiallyFrgAnimHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_fade_in, 0)
                            .add(fragmentB)
                            .commit();
                }
            }, 400);
```

Can someone give an example? How does it make correctly?